# qsort of struct array not working

Tags: c, string, struct, qsort

I am trying to sort a struct run array called results by a char, but when I print the array, nothing is sorted. Have a look at this:

```
struct run {
  char name[20], weekday[4], month[10];
  (And some more...)
};
typedef struct run run;

int name_compare(const void *a, const void *b) 
{
    run *run1 = *(run **)a;
    run *run2 = *(run **)b;
    return strcmp(run1->name, run2->name);
}

int count_number_of_different_persons(run results[])
{
  int i = 0;


  qsort(results, sizeof(results) / sizeof(run), sizeof(run), name_compare);

  for(i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", results[i].name);
  }
  // not done with this function yet, just return 0
  return 0;
}
```

The output from the above is just a list of names in the order they were originally placed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int count_number_of_different_persons(run results[])
```

This doesn't really let you use `sizeof` on the array, because array is decayed to pointer.

This

```
run *run1 = *(run **)a;
```

also looks weird, shouldn't it be

```
run *run1 = (run*)a;
```

?

Comment: `void* a` and `void* b` are pointers to the array items. If the array itself is composed of pointers to a struct typedef'd as `run`, then the correct cast of `void* a` is `(run**)a`. This is still just a pointer to a pointer, so to get the pointer to the struct, this pointer-pointer must be dereferenced. Hence, `*(run**)a`. Though it does seem like here, the array is not an array of pointers, but a straight array, thus making the correct cast as you state, `(run*)a`. (I ran into this problem just now, found this post, thought it would help someone else).

Comment: @NickBauer, I really hope it would help someone else, but I can't really decrypt it now, 4 years later, out of context and too lazy to reread and rethink the original question and answer.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is in `name_compare`. Try this instead:

```
int name_compare(const void *a, const void *b) 
{
    run *run1 = (run *)a;
    run *run2 = (run *)b;
    return strcmp(run1->name, run2->name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the following code:

As @michel mentioned, sizeof(array) provides size of the pointer, not the size of the array itself, as while passing array it is treated as a pointer. Hence either send the number of elements to the function count_number_of_different_persons or define a MACRO of number of elements.  Hope this helps. :).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NOE 3

struct run
{
    char name[20];
};

typedef struct run run;

int name_compare (const void *a, const void *b )
{
    return strcmp (((run *)a)->name, ((run *)b)->name);
}

int count_number_of_different_persons(run results[], int noOfElements)
{
    int i=0;
    qsort(results, noOfElements, sizeof (run), name_compare);
    for (i=0; i<noOfElements; i++)
        printf ("%s\n",results[i].name);
}

int main ( int argc, char * argv[])
{
    run a, b, c;
    run  arg[NOE];

    strcpy (a.name, "love");
    strcpy (b.name, "you");
    strcpy (c.name, "i");
    arg[0] = a;
    arg[1] = b;
    arg[2] = c;

    count_number_of_different_persons(arg, sizeof(arg)/sizeof(run));
};
```