# Why qsort can not work in my code?

Tags: c

My code is to sort a structure by just one field.

It is strange that it works when the length is 8 but not in 
9.Why is that and what is wrong?

```
struct node
{
   int key;//I need to sort by the key
   int val;
};
int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
return ((struct node *)a)->key > ((struct node *)b)->key;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct node *a;
    a = malloc(10 * sizeof *a);
    /*I have 8 elements*/
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
         a[i].key = 22;
    a[6].key = 21;
    a[7].key = 20;
    a[8].key = 10;
    /*Before sorting, I print it first*/
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    printf("%3d", a[i].key);
    printf("\n");
    qsort(a, 9, sizeof(struct node), comp);
    /*The sorted answer*/
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
       printf("%3d", a[i].key);
    printf("\n");
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

22 22 22 22 22 22 21 20 10

10 22 22 22 22 22 21 20 22

But when I change the length to 8, it works.

Comment: [Check here for the sample code i already answered; Hope it helps to some extend!][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354502/qsort-of-struct-array-not-working/8356007#8356007

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "length"?

- You allocate space for 10 elements.
- You sort 9 of them.
- You print 9 of them.

This code is very confusing. You need to have a single well-defined idea of how many elements you're using, and use the same everywhere. Hint: it should not be a literal number.

Also, your comparison function is wrong, it needs to return -1, 0 or 1 for elements being less than, equal to, or greater than respectively. Your function wil only return 0 or 1.

Comment: Oh it works!!! I just wonder, why my code works when I sort an integer array using the familiar comparison function?

Comment: The idea is to have a `#define`, or better yet, `int const`, of `NR_ELEMENTS` or whatever, defined to the number of elements you are working with. This makes code much clearer. (Actually, you shouldn't have "magic numbers" anywhere in your code that are *not* defined this way. The name of the constant adds meaning.)

Comment: Yes,I will.Because this code is a demo, this bugs is from my other code, so I extract this part into a demo. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison is supposed to return a value less than, equal to, or greater than zero depending on the relation of the two arguments.  For example:

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  int key_a = ((struct node *)a)->key;
  int key_b = ((struct node *)b)->key;
  if (key_a<key_b) return -1;
  if (key_a>key_b) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you means I should return a '0' when they are equal?

Comment: @Fionser: Yes, and a negative value when a should come before b.

Answer (score 0):

Please read *carefully* several times the [qsort man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html). On Linux, type `man qsort`.
If using GCC, ask for warnings and debugging info by passing `-Wall -g` to `gcc`. (With another compiler, enable all warnings and debugging info).

After a `malloc` you'll better clear the entire zone with `memset`. Actually, you should use `calloc` like

```
a = calloc (10, sizeof(*a));
if (!a) 
  perror("calloc a"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Recall that you *always* should *test* the result of `calloc` or `malloc`!

The comparator function gets the address of the things to compare, and should return a integer (0 for equality, a negative for less-than, a positive for greater-than).

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
   const struct node* na = (const struct node*) a;
   const struct node* nb = (const struct node*) b;
   return na->key - nb->key;
}
```

Please learn to use a debugger (like `gdb` on Linux).

Comment: Actually, `na->key - nb->key` might lead to overflow (for instance, assuming 2-complement, this comparison function will treat `INT_MAX` as smaller than `-1`), which makes `comp` non-transitive. This is an issue for an ordering relation.

Comment: Ok, but the compare by e.g. `<` of the same keys is, in the processor chip, doing exactly the same subtraction, but discarding the result. It is a sad fact that on rare pathological cases, computer ordering is non-transitive

Comment: I strongly suspect that the processor checks for the appropriate flag to see if an overflow occurred and returns the right answer. Of course, this is probably more difficult to do within C (at least portably).